# Are shopify apps limited to touch only products and post-sale?

Tags: ruby, shopify

I've read through all the API documentation and looked at the shopify app PixelPrinter on github and I'm not seeing anywhere in the doc's where I can have a customer add a custom dollar amount on checkout to go to a specific cause.

Is it possible to add a drop down field to the cart/checkout screen via my app (or instruct them how to add this) and have that selected value end up in the order?  Maybe i'm thinking about this all wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to collect money using Shopify, you need to sell Products. A product can have variants and each one has a dollar amount. You cannot sell any product for a random amount of money. You could create a product called Donation, and assign some values to it, allowing a customer to select from some amount of money available as a variant, which you then assign to their favorite cause.